# Safari not responding to media queries

Tags: css, media-queries

I'm probably missing something very basic here.  This code works perfect on chrome but for some reason Safari does not seem to be reading these media queries.  Any help would be appreciated.  New coder here.

```
@media screen and (max-width: 768px) {
  #wellLogo {
    height: 250px;
    margin-top: 175px;
  }

  .home1 {
    background-image: url("../assets/img/sanctuaryS.png");
  }

@media screen and (max-width: 480px) {

  .standardParallax {
    background-attachment: scroll;
    height: 175px;
  }

  #wellLogo {
    height: 100px;
    margin-top: 40px;
  }

  h1 {
  font-size: 30px;

  }

  .mission {
    display: block;
    margin: 5px;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    height: 70px;
    width: 175px;
    border-radius: 25px;
    border: 5px solid rgba(107,84,71,.9);
  }

  h5 {
    font-size: 20px;
  }

  #spanish {
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
  }

  #english {
    margin-right: auto;
    margin-left: auto;
  }

  #missionPadding {
    padding-top: 0px;
  }

  #exchange {
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    padding-top: 0px;
  }

  #elements {
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
  }

  .margin1 {
    margin-bottom: 5px;
  }

  .section {
    height: 375px;
  }

  #section1 {
    height: 400px;
  }

  .section2 {
    height: 300px;
  }

}
```

Answer (score 4):

The closing curly bracket of the first media query is missing.